# JavaScript not working in FF 5

Tags: javascript, firefox

Following line doesn't work in FF 5.

```
<a href="javascript:func1(upDiv);">Resend Pin</a>
<div id="upDiv">ASDFGHJKL</div>
```

JS function

```
function func1(windowname) {
    alert(windowname);
}
```

It works in Google Chrome and even in IE8.

Comment: if "upDiv" is simple string then pass it as string in quotes.

Comment: Is `upDiv` defined somewhere?

Comment: upDiv is the id of DIV tag defined in page.

Comment: then pass it like a string if this is id in single quotes. like <a href="javascript:func1('upDiv');">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE and Chrome have the (bad) habit of creating a global variable for each element with an ID which refers to that element.

Pass a string and use `getElementById` instead:

```
<a href="javascript:func1('upDiv');">Resend Pin</a>

function func1(windowname) {
    alert(document.getElementById(windowname));
}
```

Also, don't use the `javascript:` pseudo protocol. Either refer to a proper location so that it works if JS is disabled or use a button, and attach an event handler for the `click` event. E.g.

```
<button onclick="func1('upDiv');">Resend Pin</button>
```

You can style the button as a link if you really want to.

Comment: This works. Thanks. One more thing this is also not working: `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;` while making an Ajax request.

Comment: @mark: Well, what can I say to that? Either there is a problem with `xmlhttp` or `handleReadyStateChange`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function func1(windowname) {
    alert(document.getElementById(windowname).innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: You answered so fast. I was updating the question. It doesn't work.

Comment: What kind of variable is `upDiv`? Try using this: `alert('Window: ' + windowname);` to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mhmm works for me when you have a var upDiv defined in the global namespace: http://jsfiddle.net/vNnvg/

**Edit:**
Ahh, read your  edit question. In IE all element ids come member of the global name space, so if you have an element with id "myId", you can get it by simply call window.myId or just myId in JavaScript. this will not work in Firefox. Btw, I wonder that this works in Chrome.

Comment: upDiv is the id of DIV tag defined in page.

Comment: w3c recommends to access by getElementById() - this is preferable.